# Get ID name of a clicked element and show divs with the same name of class

Tags: javascript, jquery

My aim is to get ID name of a clicked navigation button (for example, `#cat-1` ID of `li` element which is within `ul.accordion-content` list) and show `.gallery-item` blocks which have the same name of class `.cat-1`. 
It doesn't work and I cannot figure out the reason.

```js
$("ul.accordion-content > li").on("click", function() {
  var category = $(this).id;

  if ($(".gallery-item").hasClass(category)) {
    $(".gallery-item").show();
  } else {
    $(".gallery-item").hide();
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="accordion-content">
  <li id="cat-1">Category One</li>
  <li id="cat-2">Category Two</li>
  <li id="cat-3">Category Three</li>
</ul>

<div class="gallery-item cat-1">
  <div class="item-content">Item One</div>
</div>
<div class="gallery-item cat-1">
  <div class="item-content">Item One</div>
</div>

<div class="gallery-item cat-2">
  <div class="item-content">Item Two</div>
</div>
<div class="gallery-item cat-2">
  <div class="item-content">Item Two</div>
</div>

<div class="gallery-item cat-3">
  <div class="item-content">Item Three</div>
</div>
<div class="gallery-item cat-3">
  <div class="item-content">Item Three</div>
</div>
```

They all disappear once I click one of the navigation buttons.:(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue is that `id` is not a property of a jQuery object, so `category` is being set to `undefined`. To fix this you need to use either `$(this).prop('id')` or `this.id`.

Also note that you can make the logic much more succinct by selecting the elements directly by the chosen class instead of using `hasClass()` - which would only work for the first element in the collection. Try this:

```js
$("ul.accordion-content > li").on("click", function() {
  $('.gallery-item').hide().filter('.' + this.id).show()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="accordion-content">
  <li id="cat-1">Category One</li>
  <li id="cat-2">Category Two</li>
  <li id="cat-3">Category Three</li>
</ul>

<div class="gallery-item cat-1">
  <div class="item-content">Item One</div>
</div>
<div class="gallery-item cat-1">
  <div class="item-content">Item One</div>
</div>

<div class="gallery-item cat-2">
  <div class="item-content">Item Two</div>
</div>
<div class="gallery-item cat-2">
  <div class="item-content">Item Two</div>
</div>

<div class="gallery-item cat-3">
  <div class="item-content">Item Three</div>
</div>
<div class="gallery-item cat-3">
  <div class="item-content">Item Three</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I dodn't know of such an approach. Thank you very much, Mr. McCrossan!! Now it works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Get the `id` from current clicked item, which is `this` via `this.id`, then put your logic there, hide all `.gallery-item` and then show only with `.this.id` class.

```js
$('.accordion-content li').on('click', function(){
  $('.gallery-item').hide();
  $(`.${this.id}`).show();
});
```

```css
div.gallery-item{
  display: none
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="accordion-content">
  <li id="cat-1">Category One</li>
  <li id="cat-2">Category Two</li>
  <li id="cat-3">Category Three</li>
</ul>

<div class="gallery-item cat-1">
  <div class="item-content">Item One</div>
</div>
<div class="gallery-item cat-1">
  <div class="item-content">Item One</div>
</div>

<div class="gallery-item cat-2">
  <div class="item-content">Item Two</div>
</div>
<div class="gallery-item cat-2">
  <div class="item-content">Item Two</div>
</div>

<div class="gallery-item cat-3">
  <div class="item-content">Item Three</div>
</div>
<div class="gallery-item cat-3">
  <div class="item-content">Item Three</div>
</div>
```